# Flex ActionScript XMLList Menu Bar problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, menubar, xmllist

I am working in Flex 4, and wana use MenuBar control, it requires XMLList to populate its items, but the problem is, i want to apply if conditions on sub items of my menu, let me explain my problem with example:

```
var menubarXML:XMLList;

menubarXML=
<>
   <menuitem label="File">
   <menuitem label="New Sheet" data="new_sheet"/>
   <menuitem label="Open Existing" data="open_sheet"/>
   <menuitem label="Print" data="print"/>
   //i want to apply condition here     
   <menuitem label="Save" data="save_pdf"/>
   <menuitem label="Exit" data="exit"/>
   </menuitem>
</>
```

For example, how can i apply condition like if (anyflag==true) disable my save menu sub item, of course the question is simple, and this issue can easily be tackled in Java and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have an attribute in your XML with enable = true or false;

```
<menuitem label="File">
<menuitem label="New Sheet" data="new_sheet" enable = "true"/>
<menuitem label="Open Existing" data="open_sheet" enable = "true"/>
<menuitem label="Print" data="print" enable = "false"/>
</menuitem>
```

Now while parsing your xml check whether the enable is true or false, based on that you can control your menu and its child items.

Comment: Thats all can be done easily, but the issue is IF Condition, whenever we apply any if else condition the xml stops working...

Comment: @Dilshad Anwer could you give an example, how are you applying any condition? It's not clear yet...

Comment: menubarXML=<><menuitem label="File"> if (Entry_Tag="Y") //this if is needed { <menuitem label="New Sheet" data="new_sheet" enabled="true"/> <menuitem label="Open Existing" data="open_sheet" enabled="true"/> } else { <menuitem label="New Sheet" data="new_sheet" enabled="false"/> <menuitem label="Open Existing" data="open_sheet" enabled="false"/> } <menuitem label="Print" data="print"/> <menuitem label="Save" data="save_pdf"/> <menuitem label="Exit" data="exit"/> </menuitem></>

Comment: @Dilshad, Edit your original answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also define you own discriptor for your menu in which you **override** method **isEnabled** to enable or disable an items using tag on renderering sample is as

```
public class MyDescriptor extends DefaultDataDescriptor
{

    public function MyDescriptor()
    {
        super();

    }

    override public function isEnabled(node:Object):Boolean
    {
                    return 'true'==node.anytag;
    }

}
```

and **Menu** is then created as

```
menu = Menu.createMenu(this, dataprovider, false);
menu.dataDescriptor = new MyDescriptor();
```

Hopes that helps